# How can I edit an event on one marker?

Tags: javascript, events, leaflet

I have a marker on which I add an event :

```
myMarker.on('dragend', function(event) {
            myFunctionEvent});
```

I need to edit the function event :

```
myMarker.on('dragend', function(event) {
            newFunctionEvent});
```

If I like the above, this adds a new event and both will fire.
must first be removed.

I don't want to remove the marker and create a new for this.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the previous event handler.

```
function myEvHandler(ev) {...}
myMarker.on('dragend', myEvHandler);

// Later...
myMarker.off('dragend', myEvHandler);
function myNewEvHandler(ev) {...}
myMarker.on('dragend', myNewEvHandler);
```

In order to do this, make sure that your event handler functions can be referenced to (in other words: do not create anonymous lambda-style functions).

Answer (score 0):

For adding or removing existing event in leaflet 0.7.7, you can do like this

```
L.Draggable.include({
  _onUp: function () {
    L.DomUtil.removeClass(document.body, 'leaflet-dragging');

    if (this._lastTarget) {
      L.DomUtil.removeClass(this._lastTarget, 'leaflet-drag-target');
      this._lastTarget = null;
    }

    for (var i in L.Draggable.MOVE) {
      L.DomEvent
          .off(document, L.Draggable.MOVE[i], this._onMove)
          .off(document, L.Draggable.END[i], this._onUp);
    }

    L.DomUtil.enableImageDrag();
    L.DomUtil.enableTextSelection();

    if (this._moved && this._moving) {
      // ensure drag is not fired after dragend
      L.Util.cancelAnimFrame(this._animRequest);

      this.fire('dragend', {
        distance: this._newPos.distanceTo(this._startPos)
      });

      //Put your event here
    }

    this._moving = false;
  }
});
```